# Is such way to import the NetCDF file in R correct?

Tags: coordinate-system, r, netcdf

Recently, I asked the same question on the Stack Overflow forum and was directed to this forum: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65467765/is-such-way-to-import-the-netcdf-file-in-r-correct.

To sum up, I have a CMORHP product (satellite based precipitation data) that I would like to import into R and extract point values for specific locations. An example, of the NetCDF file and stations is uploaded here: https://transferxl.com/08jzws5Rp8GPGp.

I am using next code to import the data into R and extract point values for these locations (stations):

```
library(rgdal);library(ncdf4);library(raster)
nc <- nc_open("G:/CMORPH/CMORPH_V1.0_ADJ_8km-30min_1998050101.nc",verbose=TRUE)
cshp <- readOGR(dsn="G:/CMORPH",layer="stations")
brick("G:/CMORPH/CMORPH_V1.0_ADJ_8km-30min_1998050101.nc")
data <- ncvar_get(nc, "cmorph")
data.slice <- data[, , 1] 
lon <- ncvar_get(nc, "lon")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc, "lat")
lon[lon > 180] <- lon[lon > 180] - 360
dat1 <- list(lon,lat,cbind(t(data.slice)[,2475:4948],t(data.slice)[,1:2474])) ## This could be merged with the line below
r <-raster(x=dat1[[3]],  xmn=-180, xmx=180,ymn=-60, ymx=60,crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
r <- flip(r, direction='y')
neki <- extract(r,cshp)
```

If I compare (visually)

```
plot(r)
```

and visual representation using Panoply viewer (https://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/), both plots look similar. Moreover if I compare `r` and `brick("G:/CMORPH/CMORPH_V1.0_ADJ_8km-30min_1998050101.nc")`outputs, main properties look fine. However, if I extract data for longer period (i.e. multiple months) and compare the extracted data (precipitation) with measured point data the difference is much larger as I would expect.
The code works fine but I am not completely sure if the import of the NetCDF file into R is done correctly. The main reason for my doubts is because extracted data from multiple .nc files differs significantly from measured point precipitation. Thus, I think that I could be doing something wrong when defining projection properties. Any feedback?

Comment: Add the ncdf4 and raster packages, then you can use `raster` or `stack` to read the data as a raster class object. The raster package is what you want to use for analyzing your data anyhow.

Comment: Please post a complete Question, with the code present, since convincing folks to follow links to review your code is a hard ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your example code is superfluous. You do not need to use `nc_open` you really can just use`raster::stack` or `raster::brick`. I have worked with NetCDF, from various sources, quite a bit and never had issues with simply reading them directly into a raster object. Only once did I have to flip the raster.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)
nc <- brick("G:/CMORPH/CMORPH_V1.0_ADJ_8km-30min_1998050101.nc")
```

If you are doubting the data then you need to provide us access to an example of the data so, we have a reproducible example to work with and specify exactly what your expectations are. I find it suspect that some of the timeseries seems correct. This points to a source data issue and not a read/import problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is indeed the only function that I need. Is there perhaps an easy way to change the "projection" of the data in order not to have longitude coordinate from 0 to 360 but from -180 to 180 and to obtain the same format of the data (not to define a new raster object as I did before when I used cbind of the data.slice)?